# How to track iframe changes to prevent a scrollbar from being visible or white space to be added?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I don't know If I asked my question very well on the title, but we are working with working with Pardot, Pardot allows us to create forms and inject them in other website via iframe, sounds simple, but those generated iframe has a fixed height, so in order to fix the height of iframe, a script has to be added to manage the iframe dimensions via JS.

This is the script I already found someone worked on it :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Create browser compatible event handler.

    var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";

    var eventer = window[eventMethod];


    var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";


    // Listen for a message from the iframe.

    eventer(messageEvent, function (e) {
        if (isNaN(e.data)) return;
        // replace #sizetracker with what ever what ever iframe id you need
        document.getElementById('sizetracker-1').style.height = e.data + 'px';
        document.getElementById('sizetracker-2').style.height = e.data + 'px';
        document.getElementById('sizetracker-3').style.height = e.data + 'px';

    },
        false);
    
    /* 
    eventer("resize", function (e) {
        if (isNaN(e.data)) return;

        // replace #sizetracker with what ever what ever iframe id you need
        document.getElementById('sizetracker-1').style.height = e.data + 'px';
        document.getElementById('sizetracker-2').style.height = e.data + 'px';
        document.getElementById('sizetracker-3').style.height = e.data + 'px';

    })
    
     */

</script>
```

The good news about this script, is that I no longer have a scrollbar on my iframe which is great, one problem solved already.

The bad news if that when the iframe height is not adapted exactly to the content, How ?

If the iframe has a height of 200 px & resized the window and the content became 500px ( mobile ), the iframe height changes to 500px, but when I go back to desktop mode while resizing, the iframe height does not change again! it is still 500px which is a problem because a big white space will be in the page!

First I thought that it is because the height is adjusted just when loading the page for first time ( not logical I know ), but I found out later that it is not the case! When the iframe height receive a height value via javascript, & then receive an other height via onmessage event, the max height is what applied, not the current one!

I will explain with images!

My two forms height with the script are adjusted properly :

[image]

If I validate one of them, the height is not adapted to the new height :

[image]

If I try to validate the second form with erros :

[image]

If I correct those erros, the max height what is applied :

[image]

Something when I go mobile, once my form height get a little bite bigger ( duo css media queries ), it is impossible to go back to a smaller height that fits more.

Any ideas ? Any help ?

My whole code is : ( I know it is not propper html, but that's not the point )

For the window.onresize event I added, i tried to track the window resizing, but it seems like it not the problem !

```
<iframe id="sizetracker-3" src="http://2-03/xs6" width="100%" height="100" type="text/html"
    frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border: 0; background-color: yellow; "></iframe>


<iframe id="sizetracker-1" src="http0-12-03/xs6" width="100%" height="100" type="text/html"
    frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border: 0; background-color: green; "></iframe>



<iframe id="sizetracker-2" src="http://go.pa20-12-03/xs6" width="100%" height="100" type="text/html"
    frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border: 0; background-color: red; "></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // Create browser compatible event handler.

    var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";

    var eventer = window[eventMethod];


    var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";


    // Listen for a message from the iframe.

    eventer(messageEvent, function (e) {
        if (isNaN(e.data)) return;
        // replace #sizetracker with what ever what ever iframe id you need
        document.getElementById('sizetracker-1').style.height = e.data + 'px';
        document.getElementById('sizetracker-2').style.height = e.data + 'px';
        document.getElementById('sizetracker-3').style.height = e.data + 'px';

    },
        false);

    eventer("resize", function (e) {
        if (isNaN(e.data)) return;

        // replace #sizetracker with what ever what ever iframe id you need
        document.getElementById('sizetracker-1').style.height = e.data + 'px';
        document.getElementById('sizetracker-2').style.height = e.data + 'px';
        document.getElementById('sizetracker-3').style.height = e.data + 'px';

    })

    setInterval(function () {
        // Create browser compatible event handler.

        var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";

        var eventer = window[eventMethod];


        var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";


        // Listen for a message from the iframe.

        eventer(messageEvent, function (e) {
            if (isNaN(e.data)) return;
            // replace #sizetracker with what ever what ever iframe id you need
            document.getElementById('sizetracker-1').style.height = e.data + 'px';
            document.getElementById('sizetracker-2').style.height = e.data + 'px';
            document.getElementById('sizetracker-3').style.height = e.data + 'px';

        },
            false);

        eventer("resize", function (e) {
            if (isNaN(e.data)) return;

            // replace #sizetracker with what ever what ever iframe id you need
            document.getElementById('sizetracker-1').style.height = e.data + 'px';
            document.getElementById('sizetracker-2').style.height = e.data + 'px';
            document.getElementById('sizetracker-3').style.height = e.data + 'px';

        })
    }, 100);


</script>
```

Comment: The code you have shown reacts on messages sent to the current document, but you have not shown us where those messages are actually send _from_. Presumably this is the iframes themselves, reporting their current height back. If they don’t do that properly, and don’t go back below an already previously reported larger height (could be a deliberate choice), then there is nothing you can do about that from the scope of your current document, this would need to be fixed in the code those iframes execute.

Comment: I havent add anything in the content of my iframes, so I think it is the iframes themselves reporting their current height! The problem is I don't have control over them, they are just generated !

Comment: According to all info I could find, this is not a feature Pardot offers out of the box, and a recent article like https://jennamolby.com/how-to-embed-a-pardot-form-on-your-website-the-right-way/ also suggests that this is something that needs to be explicitly implemented in the form itself.

Comment: Yup, I have implemented it, works better but lacks one things in my questions, tracking the form's height when the success message pop up, I am reading the script hoping I can a solution :D, Thanks for that!